# Show zoomed image with Glide

Tags: android, android-glide

I want to show image with specific zoom level using Glide library in Image view. I tried .centerCrop() but it zooms image very slightly. Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Does this help - https://github.com/Baseflow/PhotoView

Comment: I want to show zoomed image by default.

Answer (score 0):

> Try this

```
Glide.with(context).load("your-image-url-or-resource").override(600,200).into("your_image_view");
```

> override(600, 200) is the image dimension you wish to display the image in, and apply centerCrop. Hope this helps you.

Comment: tried but it ruins quality of image. Thanks for the help.